# Para que há tantas maneiras verificar se um valor é NULL? Como padronizar?

Tags: php, null

Há certas coisas ainda que não entram na minha cabeça em relação ao PHP.

Porque existe a função `is_null`, quando podemos simplesmente comparar os valores através de um operador de comparação. Como por exemplo `$variable === NULL`?

E por que em alguns tutoriais recomendam a "inversão" dessa verificação.

Ou seja, ao invés de usar

```
if ($variable === NULL) {
   // faça alguma coisa
}
```

Ensinam a usar:

```
if (NULL === $variable) {

  // faça alguma coisa
}
```

Mas em alguns *frameworks*, como o Laravel, vejo muito:

```
if ( is_null($variable)) {

     // faça alguma coisa   
}
```

Dizem ser mais rápido fazer como no segundo exemplo.

Mas isso é realmente uma coisa que devo me preocupar? Ou é apenas uma microotimização ridícula?

Devo parar de colocar `is_null` nos meus códigos, já que um operador de comparação consome menos recurso na memória do que um chamamento de uma função?

Existe algum padrão (algum FIG Standard) que ajude nessa tarefa, para facilitar uma padronização?

Comment: O segundo exemplo chama se não me engano verificação yoda, serve para você trocar a comparação pela atribuição em linguagens onde se usa `=` para ambos.

Comment: "Yoda conditions" para os íntimos (acabei de ver no [wikipédia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A função [`is_null()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-null.php) faz a mesmo que `NULL ===`.

Ambos fazem a mesma coisa, mas em relação a velocidade, `NULL ===` é mais rápido, 14 vezes mais rápido (segundo essa comparação [aqui](https://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/03/29/php-is_null-vs-null/)). Em relação aos vários modos de se fazer isso, cada modo tem sua particularidade, por exemplo a função [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php) retorna *true* somente quando uma variável não é nula, [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php) por sua vez retorna *true* se uma variável é uma *string* vazia, *false*, `NULL`. [`is_null()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-null.php) é o oposto de [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php), exceto que [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php) pode ser aplicável a variáveis desconhecidas, enquanto [`is_null()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-null.php) a variáveis declaradas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja também: [Tabela de comparação de tipos no PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/types.comparisons.php)

Answer (score 8):

Não existem várias formas. Ou existem se você considerar que qualquer código é possível escrever de várias formas.

A segunda forma é exatamente equivalente à primeira forma, principalmente em performance. Ela é chamada de [*yoda condition*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) como você já descobriu. Em tese ela deve ajudar descobrir erros em linguagens que permitem atribuir valor para variáveis onde normalmente se espera expressões condicionais verificando igualdade (muitas linguagens não permitem). A ideia seria provocar um erro fazendo isto:

```
if (null = $var)
```

Se você escrever do "jeito normal" isso passaria:

```
if ($var = null)
```

e `$var` receberia o valor [`null`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) e continuaria a execução do código (mas não entraria no `if` porque `$var` valeria `null` que é considerado um `false`.

Escrever

```
if(null === $var)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Typing/NullVar.php).

não traz vantagem alguma. Apenas seria vantajoso se você se equivocar e esquecer dois destes sinais de igual porque você teria um erro.

Mas sinceramente se você acha que pode cometer este tipo de erro e não perceber acho que será pior esquecer de usar `===` no lugar de `==` como quase sempre é recomendado. E não tem nada que impeça você de cometer o engano de "comer" apenas um caractere de igual. E se você costuma usar sempre três iguais, a chance de mudar de três para um caractere igual é bem menor.

Lembrando que isto pode evitar um erro de digitação mas não um erro por desconhecimento de como usar o operador certo.

[`is_null`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) é uma forma que em tese é mais lenta mas que pode deixar mais claro e evitar os problemas acima. Eu, particularmente, prefiro a forma de operador mas consigo compreender que em alguns códigos seja exigido que use a função para evitar mal entendidos. Como sempre o importante é manter a consistência. Cada um deve padronizar como quiser.

Answer (score 4):

A resposta é muito mais simples do que parece, não há diferença, esse é um dos pequenos problemas do PHP, ele não foi escrito sob uma especificação padronizada, na verdade nem sei como suas funções foram aparecendo, enfim nesse caso você pode usar o que mais lhe agradar, no fundo existe uma pequena diferença em nano segundos mas que dificilmente fará a diferença. Agora o fato é que essa função dificilmente desaparecerá pois eles provavelmente não querem criar códigos legados por causa de coisas banais como essa.